# Regex to select all characters that do not match a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm weak with regexes but have put together the following regex which selects when my pattern is met, the problem is that i need to select any characters that do not fit the pattern.

```
/^\d{1,2}[ ]\d{1,2}[ ]\d{1,2}[ ][AB]/i
```

Correct pattern is:

```
## ## ## A|B aka [0 < x <= 90]*space*[0 < x <= 90] [0 < x <= 90] [A|B]
```

EG:

- 12 34 56 A → good
- 12 34 56 B  → good
- 12 34 5.6 A  → bad - select  **.**
- 12 34 5.6 C  → bad - select **.** and **C**
- 1A 23 45 6  → bad - select **A** and **6**

Edit: 
As my impression was that regex is used to perform validation of both characters and pattern/sequence at the same time. The simple question is how to select characters that do not fit the category of non negative numbers, spaces and distinct characters.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @isherwood I figured i'd have to make multiple js calls, was just hoping that there was a cleaner/better solution. I've been able to implement  /[^0-9 AB]*/ig to ensure no illegal characters, i guess a second pass could then be used to enforce the order of allowed chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer 1

### Brief

This isn't *really* realizable with 1 regex due to the nature of the regex. This answer provides a regex that will capture the **last** incorrect entry. For multiple incorrect entries, a loop must be used. You can *correct* the incorrect entries by running some code logic on the resulting captured groups to determine why it isn't valid.

My ultimate suggestion would be to split the string by a known delimiter (in this case the space character  and then using some logic (or even a small regex) to determine why it's incorrect and how to fix it, as seen in *Answer 2*.

#### Non-matches

The following logic is applied in my second answer.

**For any users wondering what I did to catch incorrect matches:** At the most basic level, all this regex is doing is adding `|(.*)` to every subsection of the regex. Some sections required additional changes for catching specific invalid string formats, but the `|(.*)` or slight modifications of this will likely solve anyone else's issues.

Other modifications include:

- Using opposite tokens

  - For example: Matching a digit

    - Original regex: `\d`
    - Opposite regex `\D`
  - For example: Matching a digit or whitepace

    - Original regex: `[\d\s]`
    - Opposite regex: `[^\d\s]`

      - Note `[\D\S]` is **incorrect** as it matches both sets of characters, thus, any non-whitespace or non-digit character (since non-whitespace includes digits and non-digits include whitespace, both will be matched)
- Negative lookaheads

  - For example: Catching up to 31 days in a month

    - Original regex `\b(?:[0-2]?\d|3[01])\b`
    - Opposite regex: `\b(?![0-2]?\d\b|3[01]\b)\d+\b`

---

### Code

First, creating a more *correct* regex that also ensures `0 < x <= 90` as per the OP's question.

```
^(?:(?:[0-8]?\d|90) ){3}[AB]$
```

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/eeheEN/3)

```
^(?:(?:(?:[0-8]?\d|90) |(\S*) ?)){3}(?:[AB]|(.*))$
```

**Note**: This regex uses the `mi` flags (multiline - assuming input is in that format, and case-insensitive)

#### Other Formats

Realistically, this following regex would be ideal. Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't support some of the tokens used in the regex, but I feel it may be useful to the OP or other users that see this question.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/hIBOhj/1/)

```
^(?:(?:(?:[0-8]?\d|90) |(?<n>\S*?) |(?<n>\S*?) ?)){3}(?:(?<n>\S*) )?(?:[AB]|(.*))$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

The first section (sections separated by the extra newline/break) shows valid strings, while the second shows invalid strings.

```
0 45 90 A
0 45 90 B

-1 45 90 A
0 45 91 A
12 34 5.6 A
12 34 56 C
1A 23 45 6
11 1A 12 12 A
12 12  A
12 12 A
```

#### Output

```
0 45 90 A        VALID
0 45 90 B        VALID

-1 45 90 A       INVALID: -1
0 45 91 A        INVALID: 91
12 34 5.6 A      INVALID: 5.6
12 34 56 C       INVALID: C
1A 23 45 6       INVALID: 1A, 6
11 1A 12 12 A    INVALID: 12 A
12 12  A         INVALID: (missing value)
12 12 A          INVALID: A, (missing value)
```

**Note**: The last entry shows an odd output, but that's due to a limitation with JavaScript's regex engine. The *Other Formats* section describes this and another method to use to properly catch these cases (using a different regex engine)

---

### Explanation

This uses a simple `|` (OR) and captures the incorrect matches into a capture group.

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:(?:(?:[0-8]?\d|90) |(\S*) ?)){3}` Match the following exactly 3 times

  - `(?:(?:[0-8]?\d|90) |(.+))` Match either of the following

    - `(?:[0-8]?\d|90)` Match either of the following, followed by a space character  literally

      - `[0-8]?\d` Match between zero and one of the characters in the set `0-8` (a digit between `0` and `8`), followed by any digit
      - `90` Match `90` literally
    - `(\S*) ?` Capture any non-whitespace character one or more times into capture group 1, followed by zero or one space character  literally
- `(?:[AB]|(.*))` Match either of the following

  - `[AB]` Match any character present in the set (`A` or `B`)
  - `(.*)` Capture any character any number of times into capture group 2
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

---

---

## Answer 2

### Brief

This method splits the string on the given delimiter and tests each section for the proper set of characters. It outputs a message if the value is incorrect. You would likely replace the console outputs with whatever logic you want use.

### Code

```js
var arr = [
  "0 45 90 A",
  "0 45 90 B",
  "-1 45 90 A",
  "0 45 91 A",
  "12 34 5.6 A",
  "12 34 56 C",
  "1A 23 45 6",
  "11 1A 12 12 A",
  "12 12  A",
  "12 12 A"
];

arr.forEach(function(e) {
  var s = e.split(" ");
  var l = s.pop();
  var numElements = 3;
  var maxNum = 90;
  var syntaxErrors = [];
  if(s.length != numElements) {
    syntaxErrors.push(`Invalid number of elements: Number = ${numElements}, Given = ${s.length}`);
  }
  s.forEach(function(v) {
    if(v.match(/\D/)) {
      syntaxErrors.push(`Invalid value "${v}" exists`);
    } else if(!v.length) {
      syntaxErrors.push(`An empty value or double space exists`);
    } else if(Number(v) > maxNum) {
      syntaxErrors.push(`Value greater than ${maxNum} exists: ${v}`);
    }
  });
  if(l.match(/[^AB]/)) {
    syntaxErrors.push(`Last element ${l} in "${e}" is invalid`);
  }
  if(syntaxErrors.length) {
    console.log(`"${e}" [\n\t${syntaxErrors.join('\n\t')}\n]`);
  } else {
    console.log(`No errors found in "${e}"`);
  }
});
```